# using 100% height for images in a horizontal flexbox gallery

Tags: css

So... uh, I like horizontal galleries. I just can't seem to get images to behave though. Hopefully the following example should illustrate the problem -

```css
/*\

relevant css - layout and 

\*/

body {
  display:flex;
  gap:1em;
}
nav,article {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  gap:0.5em;
}
article section {
  flex:1 1 auto;
}
article img {
  display:block;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:contain;
}

/*\

irrelevent css - styling and wotnot

\*/

html,body {
  height:100%;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:1em 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
* {
  box-sizing:inherit;
}
body {
  color:rgb(232,236,246);
  background-color:rgb(34,36,38);
}
nav {
  padding:1em;
    border-radius:0 1em 1em 0;
  background-color:rgb(49,51,53);
}
nav ul {
  padding:1em;
    border-radius:0.5em;
  background-color:rgb(34,36,38);
}
nav ul li {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
article {
  padding:1em;
    border-radius:1em;
  background-color:rgb(49,51,53);
}
article header {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
article section {
    border-radius:0.5em;
  background-color:rgb(34,36,38);
}
a,a:visited {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:rgb(170,180,240);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#image-01">image 01</a></li>
    <li><a href="#image-02">image 02</a></li>
    <li><a href="#image-03">image 03</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<article>
  <header><a href="path/to/image.jpg">image 01</a></header>
  <section class="notes"></section>
  <section class="image">
    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300">
  </section>
</article>
<article>
  <header><a href="path/to/image.jpg">image 02</a></header>
  <section class="notes"></section>
  <section class="image">
    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300">
  </section>
</article>
<article>
  <header><a href="path/to/image.jpg">image 03</a></header>
  <section class="notes"></section>
  <section class="image">
    <img src="" alt="absence of a picture of Bill Murray">
  </section>
</article>
```

the images need to shrink/grow to fit into their containers, which can be done through

```
img {
    min-height:100%;
    height:0;
}
```

or

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

or a couple of other ways that at least seemed to solve the image height. But each time the width of the container wasn't dynamically re-calculated and either ignored the value, or used the un-scaled natural width, or something else equally un-satisfactory.

Apologies if this comes across a little muddled - I've been going round in circles for hours on this and have lost some of the sources and attempts that partially worked, and a few neurons along the way... any help would be greatly appreciated, and thank you for your time

Comment: Just to make sure I understand properly - do you want each image to always have 100% height but the whole image must be seen so the width will vary?

Comment: yeah @AHaworth , I do believe we are thinking of the same thing. I guess in a way it's like a vertical flow layout, except that the height and width are switched. if that makes it any clearer

Comment: Are notes sections to take a fixed height, regardless of their content, or is their height to vary with their content?

Comment: fixed height is fine if it makes things simpler @AHaworth. the notes may end up being toggleable on top of the image or something anyway so feel free to even get rid of them completely if it helps

Comment: Well, I got stuck - if you don't have <!doctype html> then width: auto seems sufficient and I got the images all equal height and widths varying as needed. With that heading though the layout does not work. Hope someone sees this and rescues me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet gives the img element height 100% and width auto.

There are two contrasting images, the original one which has aspect ratio 2/3 and another which has aspect ratio 3/2 so you can see that things adjust.

I gave up on trying to make the body flex. Instead the articles and nav are displayed inline-block, their content put in another div and the heights of the title, the notes and images put at 10%, 20%, 70% respectively.

So, this is not perfect in relation to the title in the question which specifically mentions flex, but may be an interim way forward.

```css
/*\

relevant css - layout and 

\*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  whitespace: nowrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

nav,
article {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}

article .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

header {
  height: 10%;
}

.notes {
  height: 20%;
}

.image {
  height: 70%;
}

.image img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}


/*\

irrelevent css - styling and wotnot

\*/

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  color: rgb(232, 236, 246);
  background-color: rgb(34, 36, 38);
  white-space: nowrap;
}

nav {
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 0 1em 1em 0;
  background-color: rgb(49, 51, 53);
}

nav ul {
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background-color: rgb(34, 36, 38);
}

nav ul li {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

article {
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background-color: rgb(49, 51, 53);
  display: inline-block;
}

article header {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

article section {
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background-color: rgb(34, 36, 38);
}

a,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(170, 180, 240);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#image-01">image 01</a></li>
    <li><a href="#image-02">image 02</a></li>
    <li><a href="#image-03">image 03</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<article>
  <div class="content">
    <header><a href="path/to/image.jpg">image 01</a></header>
    <section class="notes">Notes 1</section>
    <section class="image">
      <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/300">
    </section>
  </div>
</article>
<article>
  <div class="content">
    <header><a href="path/to/image.jpg">image 02</a></header>
    <section class="notes">Notes 2</section>
    <section class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1084/300/200?grayscale">
    </section>
  </div>
</article>
<article>
  <div class="content">
    <header><a href="path/to/image.jpg">image 03</a></header>
    <section class="notes">Notes 3</section>
    <section class="image">
      <img src="" alt="absence of a picture of Bill Murray">
    </section>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: article { vertical-align:top; } should throw the elements back in line

Answer (score 0):

two ways to fix it. I preferred the second ways

1st way
add `width` value in `varticle img` in css. and change `object-fit:cover`

```
article img {
  display:block;
  height:100%;
  width:200px;
  object-fit:cover;
}
```

2nd way
add `width value` in the parent element `<article>` and add `width` value as `100%` for `varticle img`.

Comment: indeed - adding a reasonably large fixed value for width (for example 100vh) along with height:0; min-height:100%; and object-fit is the only way I have found so far to get a half decent layout. Thank you for confirming my suspicions that width probably needs to be defined though